# Small generic programming issue in C

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm starting to understand the basics of generic programming in C. I'm currently building a program that says if a value occurs or not in a given sequence of number.
I think that the bug occurs in the cmpValues function. Would anyone point it out? (for example, for want=4 and v={1,2,3,4,5}, the program says that want is not in v)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void *search(const void *x, const void *t, int n, int d, int (*cmpValues)(const void *, const void *)){
    char *p = (char *)t;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        if(cmpValues(x,p+i*d))
            return p+i*d;
    return NULL;
}

int cmpValues(const void *a, const void *b){
    if((char *)a == (char *)b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("datein.txt", "r");
    FILE *g = fopen("dateout.txt", "w");
    int *v, n, i, want;
    fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
    v = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fscanf(f, "%d", v + i);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &want);
    if(search(&want, v, n, sizeof(int), cmpValues))
        fprintf(g, "The value %d is found at position %d.\n\n", want, search(&want, v, n, sizeof(int), cmpValues));
    else
        fprintf(g, "The value does bot occur in the given sequence.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: @alk I have already gone through the code. I know the problem arises within the cmpValues function, but I don't comprehend what needs to be changed.

Comment: You mentioned that "the bug". Which bug? For which input?

Comment: @Paul92 For n=5, want=4 and v=1,2,3,4,5 it says that want is not in v

Comment: I suppose that `cmpValori` used in `if(cauta(&want,v,n,sizeof(int),cmpValori))` should be `cmpValues()` function ?!!

Comment: @J.Piquard You're right. Sorry! Fixed it!

Comment: Can you tell us what `if((char *)a == (char *)b)` ought to do?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sure. That should (I repeat, should) compare the given a and b parameters. But first converting them to ascii, i believe.

Comment: @MattB Are you *quite* sure this is the smallest program you an write that displays this behavior?

Comment: This code casts the result of `malloc()` as in `v = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`.  Who or what resource suggested doing that instead of going cast-less like `v = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmpValues, you are comparing 2 objects pointed by 2 void pointers (i.e. you don't know their type, nor their size). Let's assume we are having ints, and that an int has 4 bytes, which is usually the case.

Just for the sake of it, let's assume that the a pointer has value 0x100 (i.e. points to a int from 0x100 to 0x103, inclusive) and b pointer has a value of 0x104 (i.e. points to the int from 0x104 to 0x107).

Now, you are converting them to char* (char has 1 byte) and compare the value of the pointers. Now, the type of the pointer does not matter in comparisons. In that comparison, you will compare memory addresses (in my example, 0x100 and 0x104). Obviously, the only way the function will return 1 is if the pointers would point to the same variable.

Now, in order to fix it, you should compare the values at the memory addresses pointed by your pointers. However, simply dereferencing the pointers:

```
*((char *)a) == *((char *)b)
```

won't be enough, since this would compare just the first byte of a with the first byte of b (under the assumption that char has 1 byte). Also, you can't dereference void*.

So, you need to iterate over your variables and compare them byte by byte (this assumes that you know the size of the data type):

```
int comp(void *a, void *b, int size) {
    // convert a and b to char* (1 byte data type)
    char *ca = a;
    char *cb = b;
    // iterate over size bytes and try to find a difference
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(ca + i) != *(cb + j)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // if no difference has been found, the elements are equal
    return 1;
}
```

side note: you don't need to call `cauta` twice in main.

Comment: And if I convert a and b to int instead of char?

Comment: It would work for int. But then it won't be generic in the sense that it would be able to compare any other data type (well, if you iterate as I did, you could compare any data types that have a size divisible by 4). I used char because char is the only data type of 1 byte.

Comment: Sorry for coming back, but it does not work. The problem remains regarding the sequence given in the question.

Comment: That is because there are some other issues. I fixed them here: http://pastebin.com/c49GyBK1